# Why does my bot not detect people in a role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so I've been having some issues lately with my bot. I have a command where I list the admins and mods of my server in an embed, and the embed works fine. My code is solid as well, but the problem is that the bot doesn't detect anyone in that role, even though there is clearly someone in that role. Here is my code:

```
const czarID = '763305625509167104';
const czarMember = message.guild.roles.cache.get(czarID).members;
console.log(czarMember);
const councilCzar = czarMember.array()[0].id;
```

As you can see, I properly listed the ID and used the methods correctly. I included a console.log() in order to determine what the problem is, and when I do, I get the following:

```
Collection(0) [Map] {}
```

I'm stuck on this issue, because when I try to determine the members in the Server Owner role, which would be me, which is the *exact* same code, it works perfectly fine. Here is the code for *that*:

```
const serverOwnerID = '286374957867335681';
const membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(serverOwnerID).members;
console.log(membersWithRole);
const serverOwner = membersWithRole.array()[0].id;
```

They are the exact same pieces of code, but the IDs are different, obviously. I know it isn't a fault in my coding as the Server Owner one works, but the one on top does not. Why? I *know* for a fact that there is someone in that role, but the bot isn't detecting it.

Could someone decipher this for me? I would really appreciate it! I am new to coding so I might be missing something very simple here. Thanks !

Comment: The only obvious reason is that the ID is incorrect. Do you have access to the database behind this entire thing?

Comment: No. I've copied and pasted and fully typed out the ID multiple times. I'm honestly very confused what's going on here

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the `get()` method?

Comment: I do, yes. I made sure that discord.js was required at the top of every file.

Comment: Sorry for not making my point clear. I need to see the code of it. If the ID is correct but the expected return value is not returned, then the getter must be the source of your problem. Can you post it?

Comment: `const Discord = require("discord.js");`

It's worth noting though that this same exact code worked for a different role, and it just so happens that it doesn't work for this role.